# Does the maximum of a function give the maximum of the integral of the function?

Tags: calculus, optimization

I'm looking at a proof that assumes the max of the integral of some function $f(x)$ is achieved by using the maximum/critical point of $f(x)$, why is this the case?

For example:
$$\int f(x) dx = \int A \log x + B\log(1-x) dx$$
for some constants $A$ and $B$. The proof follows that since the integral has the form $A \log x + B\log(1-x)$, for which differentiating with respect to $x$ and setting it to zero gives:
$$x = \frac{A}{A+B}$$
as a critical point, then this value gives the maximum for $\int f(x) dx$. Specifically, it shows for some maximum $x^*$ obtained from solving for the critical point, the following holds

$$\int f(x) dx \leq \int f(x^*) dx$$

Why is this true? My intuition is that since the integral is "summing" up over all possible x, then if the integrand happens to be max, the final integral sum can be max too, but the reasoning seems odd to me. Could we possibly use Jensen's inequality?

Comment: All we have is your description of this proof. Perhaps the claim is that the integral is less than or equal to the integral of the max of the integrand?

Comment: Hi @MarkL.Stone, you are right and I have updated the post in response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be misinterpreting, but it looks like the proof is claiming that
  $$ \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx \leq \int_{a}^{b} \max_{[a,b]}f(x) \, dx \tag{1}$$
Let's write $M = \max\limits_{[a,b]}f(x)$. Then $(1)$ is equivalent to
 $$ 0 \leq \int_{a}^{b} M - f(x) \, dx $$
which is certainly true, because $M - f(x) \geq 0, \, \forall x \in [a,b]$. (To prove that the integral of a non-negative function is non-negative we can use the Riemann sum definition of the integral, but basically the sum of non-negative numbers is non-negative.)

Another way to understand this intuitively is to integrate the right-hand-side of $(1)$ and rearrange to give
  $$ \frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx \leq M $$
i.e. the mean value of the function $f$ is less than or equal to its maximum value.

Finally, I will note that the maximum value of the integral does not *occur* at the maximum value of the function, in the sense that allowing $b$ to vary, it is not necessary to have $b = x^{*}$ to get the maximum area. Take $f(x) = 1 - x^{2}$ with $a = -1$, for example. We have $x^{*} = 0$ but the maximum of the integral is obtained when $b = 1$. However, it is certainly true that
  $$ \int_{-1}^{b} 1 - x^{2} \, dx \leq \int_{-1}^{b} 1 - (x^{*})^{2} \, dx $$
for all values of $b$.